# How do I ensure memory visibility in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I have a program that is structured in this way:

```
private static Map<String, PoolObject> objects = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

// Called from up to 4 different threads
public static PoolObject getObject(String id) {
    return objects.get(id);
}

// Called from only one dedicated thread
public static void addObject(String id, PoolObject object) {
    objects.put(id, object);
}

public static class PoolObject {
    private int a, b c;
    private String someString;
    ...
}
```

The fields inside any PoolObject are modified from the same dedicated thread that also calls addObject(). How do I ensure that updates to the fields inside PoolObject are visible to all reader threads? I can't modify the PoolObject class in my program as it's a part of an external library.

Comment: You mean, a PoolObject is changed while other threads might currently use it?

Comment: The basic idea is you need to guarantee a happens-before relationship between write and read. One way to do that is using a lock. Show the code you are using to update and read the fields if you need concrete advice on how to do that.

Comment: Only update objects while they are *not* contained in the map.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to write a wrapper class for `PoolObject` with `synchronized` methods, or if there are only few places where you make modifications, wrap them with `synchronized(poolObject) {}`.